# Is there a cleaner way to change attribute on multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="6" />
```

I want to change the `checked` attribute the ones with values 1, 3 and 5.  Is there a cleaner way to provide a selector than below (preferably a one-liner)?

```
$('[name="foo"][value="1"],[name="foo"][value="3"],[name="foo"][value="4"]').prop({ checked: true }).change();
```

P.S. Found a better way:

```
$('[name="foo"]').filter('[value="1"],[value="3"],[value="4"]').prop({ checked: true }).change();
```

Comment: `$('[name=foo]:odd').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @guradio There are other checkboxes on the page that might have that value - I don't control the entire page.  I would rather not do that.

Comment: @PHPglue he wants value i doubt that the index will always be the same

Answer (score 3):

Using [`prop(propertyName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) could do something like

```js
var checkVals = [1, 3 , 5];
// Adjust selector to fit needs
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(){
  return checkVals.indexOf(+this.value) > -1 || this.checked;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="6" />
```

Or using filter()

```js
var checkVals = [1, 3 , 5];
// Adjust selector to fit needs
$(':checkbox').filter(function() {
  return checkVals.indexOf(+this.value) > -1;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="6" />
```

Comment: Note that this would change the checked state of all of the checkboxes. (Which might be fine, but might not.)

Comment: @nnnnnn right, not sure either. Could use `filter()` also

Comment: @nnnnnn got it fixed with a `|| this.checked`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you know the indices you want to check beforehand, you won't have to put them in manually:

```
$([1, 3, 5].map(x => `[name="foo"][value="${x}"]`).join(",")).prop({ checked: true }).change();
```

That snippet uses fancy es6 arrow functions and template literals. If you can't use those, it looks a little nastier but still isn't too bad:

```
$([1, 3, 5].map(function(x) { return '[name="foo"][value="' + x + '"]').join(",")).prop({ checked: true }).change();
```

Finally, you can even do it without collecting them all in the same selector:

```
[1,3,5].forEach(x => { $(`[name="foo][value="${x}"]`).prop({ checked: true }).change(); });
```

Pick your poison I guess.